# How to solve "export 'ReactComponent' was not found"

Tags: reactjs

I got below issue when i run npm run webpack.

**Here is the code**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./InformationBox.module.css";
import { ReactComponent as LightBulb } from "../../../assets/icons/lightbulb-on.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Cross } from "../../../assets/icons/times-circle.svg";
   
const InformationBox = ({ children, setState }) => {
      return (
        <div className={styles.informationBox}>
          <button
            className={styles.closeMessageBox}
            onClick={() => setState((state) => ({ ...state, infoBox: "" }))}
          >
            <Cross className={styles.closeMessageBoxIcon} />
          </button>
          <LightBulb className={styles.informationBoxLogo} />
          <div className={styles.informationBoxContent}>{children}</div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default InformationBox;

**I think i have to add something here**
```

**And I got this error**

```
WARNING in ./src/components/widgets/InformationBox/InformationBox.jsx 20:40-49 
export 'ReactComponent' (imported as 'LightBulb') was not found in '../../../assets/icons/lightbulb-on.svg' (possible exports: default)
 @ ./src/components/widgets/docs/ActionProviderDocs/ActionProviderDocs.jsx 7:0-65 22:43-57
 @ ./src/components/Config.js 8:0-98 45:58-76
 @ ./src/App.js 15:0-41 29:14-20
 @ ./src/index.js 4:0-24 5:107-110
```

*I think i have to add something here*
*I have a django code integrated with it. After run the django code when i run this react code it shows the below error*

Comment: are you using `create-react-app` and is path to images correct?

Comment: maybe try `<img src={LightBulb}/>` ??

or wrapping in a svg. 
`<svg>< LightBulb className={styles.informationBoxLogo} /></svg>`

Comment: I does'nt work. Same error

Comment: Share your project structure, please.